# Docusign C# CreateEnvelope

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I have called the demo api server and I managed to execute a call successfully and managed to sign some documents. I am now moving to the production api and what I understand is that I call the login service and get the baseURL for the new api to send my Envelope but when I do that I keep getting an error when trying to send it off. The exception comes back as :

```
Error calling CreateEnvelope:
```

Here is my code when calling the Envelope

```
            ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient(loginAccount.BaseUrl);
            Configuration cfi = new Configuration(apiClient);
            string authHeader = "{\"Username\":\"" + loginAccount.Email + "\", \"Password\":\"" + docusignPassword + "\", \"IntegratorKey\":\"" + INTEGRATOR_KEY + "\"}";
            cfi.AddDefaultHeader("X-DocuSign-Authentication", authHeader);
            EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi(cfi);
            EnvelopeSummary envelopeSummary = envelopesApi.CreateEnvelope(loginAccount.AccountId, envDef);
```

The moment it his CreateEnvelope it will throw an exception.

Comment: I've quickly reviewed their SDK and your code is slightly different than the provided example. I think the best approach in troubleshooting this is to find out where it fails. Can you try to use the login api to make sure you can successfully login before trying to `CreateEnevelope` ? I'm following this [example](https://github.com/docusign/docuSign-csharp-client)

Comment: I use the login Api correctly. I know cause I get a response object with user details including the baseURL. I then use the base URL in the new ApiClient to call the CreateEnvelope. The place where the exception occurs is on the CreateEnvelope method call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to this.

Basically you need split the BaseUrl that gets returned from the login api.

BaseUrl = https://na1.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/123123123. 
SplitUrl = https://na1.docusign.net/restapi

The first url is what the login api returns to you. You would then strip out the v2/accounts/123123123 then use that as the new url for the createEnvelope.